# Implementing watch on a virtual file system - vscode.FileSystemWatcher does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We're implementing a FileSystemProvider in our vscode extension, that allows users to read and write file like entities stored somewhere else. We want to add a watcher to the FileSystemProvider.

For local files, it looked like fs.watch and vscode.createFileSystemWatcher work similarly.

I started with setting up a watch for a local directory. I'm on Insiders (Aug 16 2019 nightly build).

To test that they work, we take a basic extension, (use yeoman generator, for e.g), add a filesystemwatcher, listen to all file changes. This will listen to events emitted from the provider we built. Install this as a VSIX, and then test the provider I built.

Both  work similarly (Typescript code) for local directories.

```
const watcher = fse.watch("/", { recursive: options.recursive }, async (event: string, filename: string | Buffer) => {
            outputChannel.appendLine(`fse.watch watcher emits event: ${event} on file ${filename}`);
            this._emitter.fire([{
                type: event === 'change' ? vscode.FileChangeType.Changed : event === 'rename' ? vscode.FileChangeType.Created : vscode.FileChangeType.Deleted,
                uri: workspaceUri.with({ path: filename.toString() })
            }]);
        });
```

and

```
const watcher: vscode.FileSystemWatcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher("**", false, false, false);
            watcher.onDidChange(e => {
                outputChannel.appendLine(`vscodeFSWatch event for ${e.fsPath} has some contents changed`);
                this._emitter.fire([{ type: vscode.FileChangeType.Changed, uri: e }]);
            });
```

If I change the root path in the watch constructor call, `fse.watch(<virtualFolderURI>,...)` or 
 `vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(\`

I expect fse.watch to fail, but the createFileSystemWatcher to listen to an event, write to output, and emit it's own event. 
I don't see anything written to output by the Virtual File system's FileSystemWatcher.

Am I missing something in expecting VSCode's view of the virtual file system to set up the events?

Am I going about the wrong way in implementing the [watch method in FileSystemProvider](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L5669)?